# magento category tree menu query being called on every page

Tags: magento, tree, windows-ce, categories

I have this query being called on every page in Magento CE 1.6.2. To find out where is it being called from, I have disabled all modules, removed the customizations done but it's still being called, this query is slowing up the page loading time and am at my wit's end trying to find out how can I stop it from being executed.

The query is given below, for simplcitiy, I have removed lot of category id' to keep the sql short. It would be great if I could get solutions or hints to stop this query being called.

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu`, `core_url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '119') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '119') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1)
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '934') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '934') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` ON (core_url_rewrite.category_id=e.entity_id) AND (core_url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND core_url_rewrite.product_id IS NULL AND core_url_rewrite.store_id='1' AND id_path LIKE 'category/%') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '9') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN('105', '125', '284', '285', '286', '288', '289', '185', '463', '464', '465', '625')) AND (`e`.`entity_id` NOT IN('140', '145',  '530', '531', '775')) AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1')
```

Cheers
Arjun

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by index catalogue_url

A quick fix is to set all indexing to manual.

Then run this shell script via cron hourly:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

It indexes all but urls.

Then run this nightly:

```
<?php

echo "clearing core_url_rewrite so that indexer can repopulate immediately\n";

require_once "/home/path/to/store/app/Mage.php";
umask( 0 );
Mage::App('default');

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$query = "TRUNCATE `core_url_rewrite`";

$writeConnection->query($query);

echo "cleared\n";

$start = time();

echo "reindexing catalog_url start \n";

$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_url');
$process->reindexEverything();

$finish = time() - $start;

echo "reindexing catalog_url finished in ".$finish." seconds \n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a query that would be used for the navigation.  The magento default theme pulls the categories for the dynamic top nav in:

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

renderCategoriesMenuHtml() is called from (by default) from:

base/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `top.phtml` code with a regularly updated static version of the menus.

Create a file `menu.php` in your magento root folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();

        $block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $_menu = $block->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top');

        echo "
        <div class='nav-container'>
            <ul id='nav'>
                        $_menu
            </ul>
        </div>
        ";
?>
```

Then, in your `./shell` directory create another file, `create-category-menus.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
/[path to magento root]/menu.php > /[path to magento root]/app/design/frontend/default/[template_name]/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml.temp

rm -f /[path to magento root]/app/design/frontend/default/[template_name]/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

mv  /[path to magento root]/app/design/frontend/default/[template_name]/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml.temp  /[path to magento root]/app/design/frontend/default/[template_name]/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

chown [webserver-user].[webserver-group]  /[path to magento root]/app/design/frontend/default/[template_name]/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml
```

Now, just add the `create-category-menus.sh` to your crontab at regular intervals, say 15 minutes or so.

You'll probably need to create the folder structure for the output file, and this also assumes that your using a linux server.  If you're not then you should be.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Blocks HTML output cache. Thus the menu has to be rendered only the first pagecall. Since magento 1.7 this block isn't cached anymore and the caching needs to be enabled programmatically.